# How can i use target and alert on if?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a right click target who tell me the `id` with a right click and alert.

```js
function theFunction(e) {
  if (e == id) {
    return (alert(e.target.id));
  } else {
    return (something) ? ;
  }
}
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu="theFunction(event)"></body>
<div id="text">test</div>
<a href="1234" id="click">test a</a>
<button id="button">test bouton</button>
<textarea name="test" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10">text</textarea>
```

So I want see the `id` I click on, but if I don't click on anything that's not gonna alert me with an `"undefined"` or with a blank. So I try a if, but he doesn't work. I'm not really good on JS and I looking on internet but didn't found the solution.

Comment: You already know that `e.target.id` is the thing you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1dto423v/

Comment: I'd really suggest using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.  Press F12 to open the Browser Development tools to be able to see the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onpointerdown = function(e) {
    return e.target.id ? alert(e.target.id) : false;
}
```